# Posgres 10 database occupied more extra disk space

Tags: postgresql-10

I executed `select datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(oid)) from pg_database` in my Postgres 10 database. It gives that one of my database occupied 165 GB memory as result.

And When I executed `select pg_size_pretty(sum(pg_relation_size(oid))) from pg_class;` by selecting this database. It gives 125 GB occupied disk space.

So here I can not find out where is the other disk space (**40 GB**) used?

Is it used for caching? If so then it must not grater than 4 GB because I checked `show effective_cache_size;` it gives me 4 GB.

So can someone tell me where exactly that other disk space is used?

Comment: `pg_relation_size()` doesn't include indexes or TOAST values for the tables (but pg_database_size() does). So you probably have a lot of indexes and compressed values (e.g. `text` or `json`). The effective cache size has **nothing** to do with the size on disk (that's only RAM, not disk space).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name if you execute **select relname AS objectname, pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(oid)) from pg_class;** You can see here all index, tosat also static files included, But yes it is not included in table but as different item(object)